# How to "override" the render function?

Tags: reactjs

I'm just getting started with React. I have a project that includes many tables, some pretty complex, but all generally output a table from a set of data. Some have parent-child relationships (with toggleable child rows), and each has a slightly different format for the row output (e.g. some have buttons that open modals). Normally, I would use jQuery DataTables for this, which is easy and flexible for something like this. I'm struggling to figure out how to do it sustainably (scaleably?) in React, though.

I've written a basic table component where it accepts a set of items via props and spits out a table and handles child rows via internal state. Today I'll convert that to use two components: the table and a separate one for the rows. I really don't want to have to write X or 2X different components though (where X is the number of tables in the project), but I'm not sure how to make it reusable. All of the tables should have some things in common like style, filter capability, paging, etc., which I would try to put at the Table component level and reuse.

The best solution so far that I've thought about doing is passing in a `preRender` function via props and using that to create the actual row JSX, and having the `render` function just assemble all of those snippets into one output (which is basically what I do already but with `Array.map`. I could then provide the `preRender` via a prop (if that works), like this:

```
var Table = React.createClass({
    render: function() { // mixin?
        var rows = [];
        for (var i=0; i<this.props.items.length; i++) {
            rows.push(this.props.preRender(this.props.items[i]));
        }
        return rows; // plus html boilerplate...
    }
});

var Parent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var foodItems = this.state.foodItems;
        var drinkItems = this.state.drinkItems;
        var foodRender = function(i) { return (<tr>{i} <a href?>Buy me</a></tr>); }
        var drinkRender = function(i) { return (<tr>{i} <button>Drink me</button></tr>); }

        return (
            <Table items={foodItems} preRender={foodRender}/>
            <Table items={drinkItems} preRender={drinkRender}/>
        );
    }
});
```

Another thing I thought of was somehow passing in a different Row component to the Table component, if that's possible. I guess the root problems are:

1. The table-level stuff is very similar or identical across tables but *may* have parts needing customization per-table.
2. The rows *do things* like open popovers, so they will have a state (or need to circle around w/props).

Is there a better way to do this sort of logic/dependency injection, or will I probably just need to make a ton of slightly-different controls.

Comment: **[This link](http://javascript.tutorialhorizon.com/2014/09/13/execution-sequence-of-a-react-components-lifecycle-methods/)**  can help you if you dont know React component’s lifecycle methods

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with something like this (using ES6 syntax for brevity):

```
const FoodItem = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <tr><td>{this.props.item} <a href="something">Buy me</a></td></tr>
    );
  }
});


const DrinkItem = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <tr><td>{this.props.item} <button>Drink me</button></td></tr>
    );
  }
});


const Table = React.createClass({
  render() {
     const {items, itemComponent: ItemComponent} = this.props;

     return (
       <table>
         {items.map(item => <ItemComponent item={item} />)}
       </table>  
     );
   }
});


const Parent = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Table items={this.state.foodItems} itemComponent={FoodItem}/>
        <Table items={this.state.drinkItems} itemComponent={DrinkItem}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

An alternative pattern would be this (which is best depends on your requirements):

```
const FoodItem = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <tr><td>{this.props.item} <a href="something">Buy me</a></td></tr>
    );
  }
});


const DrinkItem = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <tr><td>{this.props.item} <button>Drink me</button></td></tr>
    );
  }
});


const Table = React.createClass({
  render() {   
     // I'm assuming you ultimately want your table to do something cleverer than just rendering a table element
     return (
       <table>{this.props.children}</table>  
     );
   }
});


const Parent = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Table>{this.state.foodItems.map(item => <FoodItem item={item} />)}</Table>
        <Table>{this.state.drinkItems.map(item => <DrinkItem item={item} />)}</Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```